# Multimeter cable standard

Tags: identification

I have heard that [multimeter cables are good for HP server plugs](https://youtu.be/WI7-XI0eMb8?t=520). What is the standard name of this type of plug, so I know what to order? I have circled it in red:

[image]

Comment: Banana plug maybe?

Comment: You may want to edit this question to be about the name of the connector, instead of how to order them.

Answer (score 7):

Typical multimeters will have female "banana jacks", but realize that multimeters use slightly different jacks than seen in many other applications.

[image: DMM banana jacks]

The male connectors that plug into the multimeter will have a sheath around them to protect from accidental contact with the metal. Notice the sheath here:

[image: banana plugs with sheath]

Look again at the multimeter female jacks in the first picture, and observe the  outer ring that allows that sheath to fit in.

Here is the exposed male version (will fit in multimeters or standard female jacks):

[image: regular male banana plug]

Standard female banana jacks would not allow for said sheath:

[image: standard female banana jack]

Comment: Added bonus... sheath also prevents cables from being "commandeered" by someone to use on their breadboard setup....

Answer (score 2):

Most multimeters use *banana plugs*.  Note that there are a few common sizes.  Measure the length and diameter of your plugs, then look around on a distributor site to see which common size they seem to be.

Comment: I then must ask how to measure the female hole diameter.

Comment: @valentin measurement is done with a measuring tool! Try a ruler, or if available, a caliper.

Comment: It's usually 4mm these days.

Answer (score 2):

Banana to anything cables?  Select "configuration and check in-stock box > search

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/test-and-measurement/test-leads-banana-meter-interface/627?k=banana&pkeyword=banana